# How to use AWS CodeCommit as repository for Spring Cloud Config

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, aws-codecommit

I am trying to use AWS CodeCommit repository with spring cloud config. I have managed to get it working with SSH. But I would like to use https instead of SSH. AWS suggest to use credential helper. Does anyone know how can I configure spring config cloud to use credential helper? I have looked [AWS CodeCommit HTTPS access without setting up credential helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862615/aws-codecommit-https-access-without-setting-up-credential-helper) But there is no answer yet and I was wondering if there is some way in spring cloud config to do it.

Comment: How did u manage to use aws codecommit with SSH in Spring Cloud Config ? I am using the property: spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/<my_repo_name>, but it always got error of USERAUTH fail

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have seen this answer yet, but this explains a little bit and the example with JGit works. [AWS CodeCommit HTTPS access without setting up credential helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862615/aws-codecommit-https-access-without-setting-up-credential-helper)

Since Spring Cloud Config doesn't yet support adding custom Credential providers you need to implement your own EnvironmentRepository.

For a POC I overrode the JGitEnvironmentRepository, and had to copy almost all the code because what I really needed to override was a private method JGitEnvironmentRepository#setCredentialsProvider. That method is where I used the code from the example I provided above.

Spring Cloud Config uses an auto config to build their MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository bean and it is annotated with @ConditionalOnMissingBean(EnvironmentRepository.class), so as long as you create a bean of that type you can override their behavior.

So with that said the SSH option is a lot cleaner until Spring expands their support for configuring custom Credential Providers or first class support for CodeCommit.

Open issue for AWS CodeCommit: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/334

Answer (score 0):

Duplication of a similar question and solution is posted there.
[AWS CodeCommit HTTPS access without setting up credential helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862615/aws-codecommit-https-access-without-setting-up-credential-helper/53637865#53637865)