# Spring Cloud Config with AWS CodeCommit vis SSH

Tags: java, git, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, aws-codecommit

I am trying to use AWS CodeCommit as a repository for Spring Cloud Config.
In terminal I can clone, push, pull, etc using git commands, such as:

```
git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/configserver
```

However, when I try to use the same codecommit repository in the Spring Cloud Config, it gives an error when trying to clone the repository (The error is below).

This is my **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Config Service</name>
    <description>This service fetches config for other service</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Brixton.SR5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is my only class in the project, to start spring boot:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;

@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my **application.properties**

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/configserver
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
server.port=9090
```

Every time I start the project I get the following error:

```
    2016-09-08 13:47:48.342 ERROR 7970 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'environmentRepository' defined in org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration$GitRepositoryConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/configserver: USERAUTH fail
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at com.zalora.ConfigServiceApplication.main(ConfigServiceApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/configserver: USERAUTH fail
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:139) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.3.201412180710-r.jar:3.5.3.201412180710-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:178) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.3.201412180710-r.jar:3.5.3.201412180710-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:125) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.3.201412180710-r.jar:3.5.3.201412180710-r]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.cloneToBasedir(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:282) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.initClonedRepository(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:183) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.afterPropertiesSet(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:135) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.afterPropertiesSet(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:64) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/configserver: USERAUTH fail
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:159) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.3.201412180710-r.jar:3.5.3.201412180710-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:136) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.3.201412180710-r.jar:3.5.3.201412180710-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:262) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.3.201412180710-r.jar:3.5.3.201412180710-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:161) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.3.201412180710-r.jar:3.5.3.201412180710-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.3.201412180710-r.jar:3.5.3.201412180710-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.3.201412180710-r.jar:3.5.3.201412180710-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1115) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.3.201412180710-r.jar:3.5.3.201412180710-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:130) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.3.201412180710-r.jar:3.5.3.201412180710-r]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: USERAUTH fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthPublicKey.start(UserAuthPublicKey.java:118) ~[jsch-0.1.50.jar:na]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:463) ~[jsch-0.1.50.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:116) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.3.201412180710-r.jar:3.5.3.201412180710-r]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

Any help with this matter would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
P.S.: I know there i a similar question [How to use AWS CodeCommit as repository for Spring Cloud Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206869/how-to-use-aws-codecommit-as-repository-for-spring-cloud-config) But it doesn't answer my question, or provided me any help.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: This problem is due rejecting the HostKey value, I'll keep you posted if I find any solution on this problem

Answer (score -1):

Based on your example of connecting via the command line, it looks like you have probably followed [these directions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-without-cli.html#setting-up-without-cli-configure-client) to configure SSH with a default user name for AWS CodeCommit.  JGit (which Spring Cloud Config seems to be using) uses Jsch to connect to a git repository over SSH, and although Jsch is able to detect your default SSH key, it probably does not read your SSH config file to determine which user name to use.

You might try putting the SSH key ID (e.g. `APKAEIBAERJR2EXAMPLE`, which you might have configured in the "User" line of your `~/.ssh/config` file) in the URL that you configure for Spring Cloud Config.  Your `application.properties` file would look something like this:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=ssh://APKAEIBAERJR2EXAMPLE@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/configserver
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
server.port=9090
```

Comment: For some reason, it didnt work. Still get the same error. Any possible solution ?

Comment: This one is not working because when you do ssh://<userid>@<repo> the resultant is not a proper ssh url to the repo.